# An antonym for 'sought-after'

Tags: phrases, antonyms, hyphenation, prefixes, neologisms

Whenever describing something that is seldom looked for or desired I often verbalise it with `"ill sought after"` without hesitating.

<sub>(ignore that `ill` is its own word, the trouble I'm having writing it in the question..is the question)</sub>
However, I went to write an email with this phrase and no matter how I wrote it it looked really odd.

`ilsought after`? I don't think that's a word, maybe I could coin it with a cheeky hyphen
`il-sought after`? Seems like I'm only negating sought, not the whole phrase
`il-sought-after`? No, no, I need help now.

So, is there a different prefix I'm *supposed* to be using? Should `sought after` be hyphenated? Is there already a phrase that already means this I'm forgetting? <sub>(I really like 'sought after', though..)</sub>

Comment: I might use *undesirable* or *unwanted*.

Comment: I feel it sounds too strong. Like the difference between not liking something, and *disliking* something. It's just...not sought after [frequently/by most], haha

Comment: Perhaps *rarely sought after*, then.

Comment: perhaps. I'll wait to see if anyone else chimes in. Maybe it's my fault for using a strong a term as 'antonym'

Comment: *ill sought-after* (to me) sounds like something that if you did seek after it, would bring nothing but pain and suffering.

Comment: you could just say it's "*meh*".

Comment: I hit this problem again with `non-user friendly`,  if anyone later comes along; [I didn't have to ask a new question](http://forum.wordreference.com/threads/compound-adjective-with-two-hyphens-non-user-friendly.2058217/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use "unsought" as an adjective instead.

> The product was not sought-after by customers.
>
> The product was unsought by customers.

Answer (score 1):

It depends a bit on why something is not in demand.

Is it just [ignored](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/ignore)?

> Refuse to take notice of or acknowledge; disregard intentionally

Or may it be [rarefied](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/rarefied)?

> Distant from the lives and concerns of ordinary people; esoteric

Or plainly [obscure](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/obscure)?

> Not important or well known

Maybe it just went out of fashion and has become [irrelevant](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/irrelevant).

> Not connected with or relevant to something

References:
http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/ignore
http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/rarefied
http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/obscure
http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/irrelevant

Comment: I liked rarefied, well suited to what I meant, but it feels pompous to use

Comment: Unpopular works as well.